# How to configure Buildbot to poll a private git repo?

Tags: git, buildbot

How do you configure Buildbot to poll a private Git repository?

The [GitPoller](http://docs.buildbot.net/0.8.12/manual/cfg-changesources.html#chsrc-GitPoller) docs don't make any mention of private repos. The file structure under my `master/gitpoller-workdir` looks suspiciously like a typical `.git` repo folder, so I'm assuming if I modify the `config` file to include something like:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@myprivatehost.com:myuser/myprivateproject.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

then it should work assuming the my private SSH key is loaded somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Buildbot now supports specifying private SSH keys (these changes will be released as part of buildbot 1.3.0). See https://github.com/buildbot/buildbot/pull/4178.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of these PR :-)

Answer (score 2):

All configurations should be inside **master.cfg** file. I don't think modifying `master/gitpoller-workdir` would be a good idea. You can access a git repository inserting the username and password in the URL:

```
git clone http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@example.com:foobaz/myrepo.git
```

Acessing in this way will directly access to your private repository. In the **master.cfg** file it will look like this:

```
c['change_source'].append(changes.GitPoller
    ("http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@example.com:foobaz/myrepo.git",
    workdir='gitpoller-workdir', 
    branch='master',
    pollinterval=120)
```

Comment: My remote repo only allows SSH keys, not passwords. Does Buildbot support that?

Comment: Buildbot 1.3.0 will support this.

Answer (score 1):

BuildBot seems to be using the underlying `git` OS command for [GitPoller](http://docs.buildbot.net/current/manual/cfg-changesources.html#gitpoller), which itself is just going to call `ssh`,

```
gitbin
    path to the Git binary, defaults to just 'git'
```

so I think you can just use standard `~/.ssh/config` declarations to provide the key for the private repo. Create a declaration that uses your specific key in the worker (and the buildmaster) home directories similar to this;

```
# cat /home/worker/.ssh/config

Host github.com
  ClearAllForwardings yes
  User git
  IdentityFile /home/worker/.ssh/id_rsa.github-somekey-specific-to-github
```

And then the buildbot will use that key.

I think if you want to use a per repo key, then that could be done like so;

```
Host repo_1_github.com
  Hostname github.com
  ClearAllForwardings yes
  User git
  IdentityFile /home/worker/.ssh/id_rsa.github-somekey-specific-to-github

Host repo_2_github.com
  Hostname github.com
  ClearAllForwardings yes
  User git
  IdentityFile /home/worker/.ssh/id_rsa.github-some-other-key
```

and then adjust your urls in buildbot appropriately;

```
git@repo_1_github.com:organization/my_repo_thing_1.git
git@repo_2_github.com:organization/my_repo_thing_2.git
```